# Format String "Hello\World" to "HelloWorld"

Tags: c#

I loop the value on first column each row of datagridview, and the format has "\" in the middle, how do we convert convert the string without "\"

ex.

```
"Hello\World" to  "HelloWorld"
"Hi\There" to "HiThere""
```

etc

Answer (score 8):

[String handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(VS.71).aspx)

```
string hello = "Hello\\World";
string helloWithoutBackslashes = hello.Replace("\\",string.Empty);
```

or, using the @ operator

```
string hi = @"Hi\There";
string hiWithoutBackslashes = hi.Replace(@"\",string.Empty);
```

Comment: This won't compile unless you use @fixed.

Comment: ChaosPandion: "@fixed", thanks. I always forget that's a keyword.

Comment: fixed is a keyword in C# that tells the garbage collected not to move around a block of memory. It can only be used in an unsafe context.

Comment: Ummm... there's no mention of anything in unsafe context here....is there pointers involved, if so, then fixed/unsafe keywords would be used. Can you please edit the question as you have confused me?

Comment: the @ is a verbatim string in which no escaping of back slashes occur so what has that to do with fixed keyword?

Comment: @tommie: The thing is I had named the variable 'fixed' so my answer wouldn't compile. I edited the answer so it compiles. @ChaosPandion: What you've done is not very practical, at the very least receive the undesired characters as a parameter. Also it fits as at least a static method or an extension method.

Comment: Actually What I meant was I caused confusion by mentioning unsafe code. As for my answer, I meant to post it as a form of protest to multiple people posting the same exact answer. I hope no one ever uses my code even though it would work.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would mix it up a bit.

```
public class StringCleaner
{
    private readonly string dirtyString;

    public StringCleaner(string dirtyString)
    {
        this.dirtyString = dirtyString;
    } 

    public string Clean()
    {
        using (var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
        {
            foreach (char c in dirtyString)
            {
                if (c != '\\') sw.Write(c);
            }

            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use a StringWriter to mix it up more/speed up?

Comment: Man, you gotta cache the lazy execution.